# Camera resolution openCV

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-camera

I'am currently working on an Android application and I need to be able to :

Find square on a preview Camera. that part is working.
The problem that I have is, in order to be able to find these square on the Camera preview, I need to change my Camera resolution to 800x600 in order to have something smooth.

What I want is : As soon as I hit my button I want to capture the image in a specific resolution (1920x1080 for example). So basically the preview have to be in 800x600 but the capture have to be in 1920x1080.

I'am using openCV to process my camera view on live.

Comment: Can't you have the preview always at 1920x1080, and work on _resized_ frames?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing ! Thanks !